# Match one column's dataframe to another dataframe with a series of columns and extracting the columns header - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so, I have two dataframes and I'm attempting the match the column 'numbers' from dataframe 1 to the content of the full dataframe 2, and extract the column header and use that as a label/new column in dataframe 1. Struggling to build a pipeline for this though. I am working in Python.

dataframe 1

| numbers |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 101 |
| 102 |
| 103 |
| 200 |
| 201 |
| 202 |
| 203 |
| 300 |
| 301 |
| 302 |
| 303 |

dataframe 2:

| construction | fields | plates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 101 | 201 | 301 |
| 102 | 202 | 302 |
| 103 | 203 | 303 |

output [with new column label matched from dataframe 2]:

| numbers | label |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | construction |
| 101 | construction |
| 102 | construction |
| 103 | construction |
| 200 | fields |
| 201 | fields |
| 202 | fields |
| 203 | fields |
| 300 | plates |
| 301 | plates |
| 302 | plates |
| 303 | plates |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `melt` to flatten your second dataframe then `merge` it with your first dataframe:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2.melt(var_name='label', value_name='numbers'), on='numbers')
    numbers         label
0       100  construction
1       101  construction
2       102  construction
3       103  construction
4       200        fields
5       201        fields
6       202        fields
7       203        fields
8       300        plates
9       301        plates
10      302        plates
11      303        plates
```

After `melt`, your second dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df2.melt(var_name='label', value_name='numbers')
           label  numbers
0   construction      100
1   construction      101
2   construction      102
3   construction      103
4         fields      200
5         fields      201
6         fields      202
7         fields      203
8         plates      300
9         plates      301
10        plates      302
11        plates      303
```

Another way with `map`:

```
df1['label'] = df1['numbers'].map(df2.melt().set_index('value').squeeze())
print(df)

# Output
    numbers         label
0       100  construction
1       101  construction
2       102  construction
3       103  construction
4       200        fields
5       201        fields
6       202        fields
7       203        fields
8       300        plates
9       301        plates
10      302        plates
11      303        plates
```

Comment: amazing! works perfectly -- thank you!

Comment: @TomBenson. Glad it works ! You have a new [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) now :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400 ;-)

Comment: ohh nice! Thank you. You got my first vote ;)

Comment: And you my last one (until the next time) :)